# SQL Server Agent Error on running an SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-agent

When trying to execute an SSIS package I get the following error:

```
 Date      14/08/2013 15:02:42 Log     Job History (test)

 Step ID       1 Server        YGAL1-MOBL1 Job Name        test Step Name      ssis
 Duration      00:00:00 Sql Severity       0 Sql Message ID        0 Operator
 Emailed        Operator Net sent       Operator Paged      Retries Attempted      0

 Message Executed as user: GER\YGAL1-MOBL1$. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
 Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 64-bit  Copyright
 (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
 15:02:42  Error: 2013-08-14 15:02:42.84     Code: 0xC0011007    
 Source: {0AF31012-7A56-4B28-92EF-BE439E68E6F0}      Description:
 Unable to load the package as XML because of package does not have a
 valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be posted.  End
 Error  Error: 2013-08-14 15:02:42.84     Code: 0xC0011002     Source:
 {0AF31012-7A56-4B28-92EF-BE439E68E6F0}      Description: Failed to
 open package file "C:\Users\ygal1\Documents\Visual Studio
 2008\Projects\Integration Services Project2\Integration Services
 Project2\Package.dtsx" due to error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.". 
 This happens when loading a package and the file cannot be opened or
 loaded correctly into the XML document. This can be the result of
 either providing an incorrect file name was specified when calling
 LoadPackage or the XML file was specified and has an incorrect format.
 End Error  Could not load package "C:\Users\ygal1\Documents\Visual
 Studio 2008\Projects\Integration Services Project2\Integration
 Services Project2\Package.dtsx" because of error 0xC0011002. 
 Description: Failed to open package file
 "C:\Users\ygal1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Integration
 Services Project2\Integration Services Project2\Package.dtsx" due to
 error 0x80070005 "Access is denied.".  This happens when loading a
 package and the file cannot be opened or loaded correctly into the XML
 document. This can be the result of either providing an incorrect file
 name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML file was
 specified and has an incorrect format.  Source:
 {0AF31012-7A56-4B28-92EF-BE439E68E6F0}  Started:  15:02:42  Finished:
 15:02:42  Elapsed:  0.046 seconds.  The package could not be found. 
 The step failed.
```

Any ideas on how can I solve it?

Comment: What happens when you rigt click on the package and select to view the code? Does the packege open in a right way? Try to execute VS Studio with administrative rights. If the error is comming from the agent it seems that it does not have the appropriate rights to execute the package. Give all and remove one by one to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar problem and what i did to get my package to run was:
  a. Open Job properties in SQL Server
  b. On the Steps page in the Package field: I used the entire folder name instead of the mapped name, for example: \share\allusers\myuserid\mypackage.dtsx instead of A:\mypackage.dtsx

Best.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the Service account for the SQL Agent doesn't have permissions to read package.dtsx.

Maybe check which account is running the SQL Agent & give it NTFS read permissions to C:\Users\ygal1\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Integration Services Project2\Integration Services Project2

Or store the DTSX file in a location the SQL Agent account can access?